# __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given) When Migrating using South with Custom Fields

Tags: django, migration, django-south

**i am new to south and i followed their documentation and after initializing south migrations, after running**

```
manage.py migrate appname
```

**for the following custom models Models i added introspection rules as follows**

Models:

```
class DependentIntegerField(models.IntegerField):

     def __init__(self, default_callable, *args, **kwargs):
          self.default_callable = default_callable
          super(DependentIntegerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
          if not add:
               return super(DependentIntegerField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)

          return self.default_callable(model_instance)

class Level(models.Model):
     group = models.ForeignKey(Level_Group)
     number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)#null=True, blank=True
     threshold = DependentIntegerField(lambda mi:mi.number*50,null=False,blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
          return '%s' %(self.number)

     def get_fib(self):
          return fib(self.number+3)

class Gallery (models.Model):
     contractor = models.ForeignKey(Contractor)
     image = StdImageField(upload_to='GalleryDB', size=(640, 480,True))
     Title = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank = True)
     Caption = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True,blank=True)
```

Introspection Rules :

```
add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [Level], # Class(es) these apply to
        [],         # Positional arguments (not used)
        {           # Keyword argument
            "threshold": ["threshold", {}],
        },
    ),
], ["^shoghlanah\.models\.DependentIntegerField"])

add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [Gallery], # Class(es) these apply to
        [],         # Positional arguments (not used)
        {           # Keyword argument
            "image": ["image"], "upload_to": ["GalleryDB"]
        },
    ),
], ["^stdimage\.fields\.StdImageField"])
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 107, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/__init__.py", line 219, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 235, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 310, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 99, in run
    south.db.db.current_orm = self.orm(migration)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 260, in orm
    return migration.orm()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/utils/__init__.py", line 62, in method
    value = function(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/migration/base.py", line 427, in orm
    return FakeORM(self.migration_class(), self.app_label())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/orm.py", line 45, in FakeORM
    _orm_cache[args] = _FakeORM(*args) 
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/orm.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.models[name] = self.make_model(app_label, model_name, data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/orm.py", line 317, in make_model
    field = self.eval_in_context(code, app, extra_imports)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/south/orm.py", line 235, in eval_in_context
    return eval(code, globals(), fake_locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

i am little sure it's from the field `DependentIntegerField` but i don't know which `__init__` is it trying to call and i tried

```
"threshold": ["threshold", {"ldefault_callable":default_callable}],
```

but i get

```
NameError: name 'default_callable' is not defined
```

and i have no clues how to fix this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

## How to pass callable argument to field used in south

You have such field class and you want to make it work with south --- problem is with default_callable argument that is a callable and cannot be frozen.

```
class DependentIntegerField(models.IntegerField):

 def __init__(self, default_callable, *args, **kwargs):
      self.default_callable = default_callable
      super(DependentIntegerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Ignore this argument

What about leaving this argument altogether --- make it optional on the field and remove this argument from intrspection  rules (so south with ignore it's existence) --- I gather that callable argument won't change database behaviour of field --- and that is the only thing south is concerned with. Either allow nulls in this argument (and make the field fail when performing database operations --- like saving model instance --- with null `default_callable`.

It will be OK during south run because south doesn't save any models --- it just creates database tables, and during normal operations model definitions will be taken from `models.py` file that will have `default_callable` set.

## Pass information about what function to call

In some module create a dictionary od `default_callable` functions that are accessible by string keys.

Change your field so:

```
 class DependentIntegerField(models.IntegerField):

 def __init__(self, default_callable="foo.bar", *args, **kwargs):
      self.default_callable = default_callable #it it string now!
      super(DependentIntegerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

 @property
 def default_fun(self):
     return registry[self.default_callable]
```

Where registry is this dictionary of all default functions.

Comment: and how can i allow it to be null ?

Comment: Well you'll have to do some logic that is particular to your application.

Comment: Please, fix the typo: abour » about.

Answer (score 1):

Well south with custom fields can be a mess, introspection rules basically tell south what and how properties translate to constructor arguments. For example `to` constructor argument from `ForeignKey` translates to property `field.rel.to`. Moreover you define introspections *for fields* and not *for models*

The same with your code: when constructing constructor call to your field south must know that field property `default_callable` translates to constructor argument of the same name. So I gather that your introsbection rules should be defined like that:

```
add_introspection_rules([
(
    [DependentIntegerField], # Notice it is for a field not a model 
    [],         # Positional arguments (not used)
    {           # Keyword argument
        "default_callable": ["default_callable", {'default' : <<some defined constant>>}],
    },
),
], ["^shoghlanah\.models\.DependentIntegerField"])
```

As for:

```
  NameError: name 'default_callable' is not defined
```

i guess that function default_callable was not defined in the current scope.

Comment: actually after a lot of research, i found "Wont Fix" Tickets for a lot of problems caused by the callable function and South aren't willing to solve this issue currently, also i tries the solution i get nearly the same problem "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/south-users/MoA7BMWs7ZI) , and i don't know actually how to improve my model to perform the same functionality without using callable.